# Sending out a csv attachment with Django Email, is forcing the COLUMN_HEADERS into the next row if they are over 998 characters long

Tags: python, django, csv

## Steps to reproduce:

1) Get a LONG line of comma separated values (mine starts balking at 998 characters).

2) Send that out through Django Email:
`message.attach('some.csv', csv_file, 'text/csv')`

3) Open file in email, and notice that your values have been written to the second row, instead of staying all on one row.

## Input/Output

Input:

`csv_file = 'FIELD_1,FIELD_2,FIELD_3,...,FIELD_998, FIELD_999'`

Expected Output (all on one row):

`FIELD_1 | FIELD_2 | FIELD_3 | ... | FIELD_998 | FIELD_999`

Actual Output:

`FIELD_1 | FIELD_2 | FIELD_3 | ... | FIELD_
    998 | FIELD_999`

(Please note this is an example, it starts to balk at 998 char's not specifically strings)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening through the django email attachment being sent as a `text/csv` and the limitations of that. It's almost acting like a 'word wrap'. Changing `text/csv` to `application/octet-stream`, leaves the data as-is.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects